# Django PostgreSQL Database [Data Race?]

Tags: sql, django, heroku

I have a Django application hosted on Heroku using the PostgreSQL database addon. Upon performing a GET request for the front page, my applications performs a SQL query to extract some necessary display information. I also create a subprocess with Popen on each GET request.

However, when I notice that the number of GET requests increasing to around once every second, I being erroring at the statement `model.objects.get(id="----")`. I get an OperationalError ; I'm assuming that either my free plan on heroku isn't keeping up or my database isn't keeping up.

In this case, I don't want to leave Heroku's free plan, but I was wondering if I did, would I need to create more workers? Upgrade my database? What are ways to diagnose the issue? And why would a simple SQL query cause issues as the number of requests increase to an interval of around once every second? Does this seem reasonable?

My hack solution was just to sleep the view whenever I catch an OperationalError. Any other approaches recommended?

Comment: can you post the full exception ?